# How do I increase an INT value in a postgres vote table

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I created an API for voting a question, but its not working. How can I implement vote to increase no_votes by 1 whenever the upvote api is called on. Here is what I have tried

```
exports.upvote_question = async (req, res) => {
    const text = `INSERT INTO 
    votes(id, questionId, userId, no_votes, createdOn) 
    VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) 
    returning *`;
    const votes =`UPDATE votes
    SET no_votes = total + 1
      returning *`;
    const values = [
        uuidv4(),
        req.params.questionId,
        req.params.userId,
        0,
        moment(new Date())
    ];
    try {
        const { rows } = await db.query(text, values);
        return res.status(201).json({
            message: 'vote successful',
            votes: rows[0],
            request: {
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/upvote/' + rows[0].id 
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            error: console.error(err)});
    }
};
```

Comment: SET no_votes = no_votes + 1

Comment: This the error I received ```error: invalid input syntax for integer: "UPDATE votes
    SET no_votes = no_votes + 1
      returning *" ```